# Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; Paypal_Lib has a deprecated constructor

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

i have problem with my paypal lib
"  Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; Paypal_Lib has a deprecated constructor "

and also

" Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /storage/ssd2/550/3425550/public_html/system/core/Exceptions.php:271) "

this is source paypal lib

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');  
class Paypal_Lib { 
var $last_error;            // holds the last error encountered 
var $ipn_log;               // bool: log IPN results to text file? 

var $ipn_log_file;          // filename of the IPN log 
var $ipn_response;          // holds the IPN response from paypal    
var $ipn_data = array();    // array contains the POST values for IPN 
var $fields = array();      // array holds the fields to submit to paypal 

var $submit_btn = '';       // Image/Form button 
var $button_path = '';      // The path of the buttons 

var $CI; 

function Paypal_Lib() 
{ 
    $this->CI =& get_instance(); 
    $this->CI->load->helper('url'); 
    $this->CI->load->helper('form'); 
    $this->CI->load->config('paypallib_config'); 

    $this->paypal_url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'; 
    if ( $this->CI->config->item('paypal_lib_sandbox_mode') ) 
        $this->paypal_url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'; 

    $this->last_error = ''; 
    $this->ipn_response = ''; 

    $this->ipn_log_file = $this->CI->config->item('paypal_lib_ipn_log_file'); 
    $this->ipn_log = $this->CI->config->item('paypal_lib_ipn_log');  

    $this->button_path = $this->CI->config->item('paypal_lib_button_path'); 

    // populate $fields array with a few default values.  See the paypal 
    // documentation for a list of fields and their data types. These defaul 
    // values can be overwritten by the calling script. 
    $this->add_field('rm','2');            // Return method = POST 
    $this->add_field('cmd','_xclick'); 

    $this->add_field('currency_code', $this->CI->config->item('paypal_lib_currency_code')); 
    $this->add_field('quantity', '1'); 
    $this->button('Pay Now!'); 
} 

function button($value) 
{ 
    // changes the default caption of the submit button 
    $this->submit_btn = form_submit('pp_submit', $value); 
} 

function image($file) 
{ 
    $this->submit_btn = '<input type="image" name="add" src="' . base_url() . $this->button_path .'/'. $file . '" border="0" />'; 
} 


function add_field($field, $value)  
{ 
    // adds a key=>value pair to the fields array, which is what will be  
    // sent to paypal as POST variables.  If the value is already in the  
    // array, it will be overwritten. 
    $this->fields[$field] = $value; 
} 

function paypal_get_request_link() { 
    $url = $this->paypal_url . '?'; 

    foreach ( $this->fields as $name => $value ) 
        $url .= $name . '=' . $value . "&"; 

    return $url; 
} 

function paypal_auto_form()  
{ 
    // this function actually generates an entire HTML page consisting of 
    // a form with hidden elements which is submitted to paypal via the  
    // BODY element's onLoad attribute.  We do this so that you can validate 
    // any POST vars from you custom form before submitting to paypal.  So  
    // basically, you'll have your own form which is submitted to your script 
    // to validate the data, which in turn calls this function to create 
    // another hidden form and submit to paypal. 

    $this->button('Click here if you\'re not automatically redirected...'); 

    echo '<html>' . "\n"; 
    echo '<head><title>Processing Payment...</title></head>' . "\n"; 
    echo '<body onLoad="document.forms[\'paypal_auto_form\'].submit();">' . "\n"; 
    echo '<p>Please wait, your order is being processed and you will be redirected to the paypal website.</p>' . "\n"; 
    echo $this->paypal_form('paypal_auto_form'); 
    echo '</body></html>'; 
} 

function paypal_form($form_name='paypal_form')  
{ 
    $str = ''; 
    $str .= '<form method="post" action="'.$this->paypal_url.'" name="'.$form_name.'"/>' . "\n"; 
    foreach ($this->fields as $name => $value) 
        $str .= form_hidden($name, $value) . "\n"; 
    $str .= '<p>'. $this->submit_btn . '</p>'; 
    $str .= form_close() . "\n"; 

    return $str; 
} 

function validate_ipn() 
{ 
    // parse the paypal URL 
    $url_parsed = parse_url($this->paypal_url);         

    // generate the post string from the _POST vars aswell as load the 
    // _POST vars into an arry so we can play with them from the calling 
    // script. 
    $post_string = '';    
    if (isset($_POST)) 
    { 
        foreach ($_POST as $field=>$value) 
        {       // str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $value) 
                // put line feeds back to CR+LF as that's how PayPal sends them out 
                // otherwise multi-line data will be rejected as INVALID 

            $value = str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $value); 
            $this->ipn_data[$field] = $value; 
            $post_string .= $field.'='.urlencode(stripslashes($value)).'&'; 

        } 
    } 

    $post_string.="cmd=_notify-validate"; // append ipn command 

    // open the connection to paypal 
    $fp = fsockopen($url_parsed['host'],"80",$err_num,$err_str,30);  
    if(!$fp) 
    { 
        // could not open the connection.  If loggin is on, the error message 
        // will be in the log. 
        $this->last_error = "fsockopen error no. $errnum: $errstr"; 
        $this->log_ipn_results(false);         
        return false; 
    }  
    else
    {  
        // Post the data back to paypal 
        fputs($fp, "POST $url_parsed[path] HTTP/1.1\r\n");  
        fputs($fp, "Host: $url_parsed[host]\r\n");  
        fputs($fp, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");  
        fputs($fp, "Content-length: ".strlen($post_string)."\r\n");  
        fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");  
        fputs($fp, $post_string . "\r\n\r\n");  

        // loop through the response from the server and append to variable 
        while(!feof($fp)) 
            $this->ipn_response .= fgets($fp, 1024);  

        fclose($fp); // close connection 
    } 

    if (eregi("VERIFIED",$this->ipn_response)) 
    { 
        // Valid IPN transaction. 
        $this->log_ipn_results(true); 
        return true;          
    }  
    else 
    { 
        // Invalid IPN transaction.  Check the log for details. 
        $this->last_error = 'IPN Validation Failed.'; 
        $this->log_ipn_results(false);    
        return false; 
    } 
} 

function log_ipn_results($success)  
{ 
    if (!$this->ipn_log) return;  // is logging turned off? 

    // Timestamp 
    $text = '['.date('m/d/Y g:i A').'] - ';  

    // Success or failure being logged? 
    if ($success) $text .= "SUCCESS!\n"; 
    else $text .= 'FAIL: '.$this->last_error."\n"; 

    // Log the POST variables 
    $text .= "IPN POST Vars from Paypal:\n"; 
    foreach ($this->ipn_data as $key=>$value) 
        $text .= "$key=$value, "; 

    // Log the response from the paypal server 
    $text .= "\nIPN Response from Paypal Server:\n ".$this->ipn_response; 

    // Write to log 
    $fp=fopen($this->ipn_log_file,'a'); 
    fwrite($fp, $text . "\n\n");  

    fclose($fp);  // close file 
} 


function dump()  
{ 
    // Used for debugging, this function will output all the field/value pairs 
    // that are currently defined in the instance of the class using the 
    // add_field() function. 

    ksort($this->fields); 
    echo '<h2>ppal->dump() Output:</h2>' . "\n"; 
    echo '<code style="font: 12px Monaco, \'Courier New\', Verdana, Sans-serif;  background: #f9f9f9; border: 1px solid #D0D0D0; color: #002166; display: block; margin: 14px 0; padding: 12px 10px;">' . "\n"; 
    foreach ($this->fields as $key => $value) echo '<strong>'. $key .'</strong>:  '. urldecode($value) .'<br/>'; 
    echo "</code>\n"; 
}
```

}

Comment: Looks as though there is a newer version of this class which you will have to upgrade to.

Comment: @NigelRen where should I change that?

Comment: Dirty fix would be changing `function Paypal_Lib()` to `public function __construct()` but you should consider changing that code to be compliant with new(er) PHP versions regarding syntax. Best would be to use official PayPal sdk repository through composer.

Comment: @Tpojka it's work